# Refrigerated vacuum Soxhlet extraction

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry, phase-diagram

Say one wanted to efficiently extract a temperature sensitive and easily oxidized compound from a substance.

I envision a Soxhlet apparatus filled with a very low BP solvent like diethyl ether. Rather than cooling the condenser column to room temperature a refrigeration loop would cool it well below. A vacuum would be pulled until the ether boils at RT.

I cannot find any evidence of this being done which makes me think my reasoning must be flawed.

Comment: Chemistry SE might be a better place?

Comment: Do you want to operate the system at low pressure and use refrigeration system to condense the vapour? And you are doing it considering the fact that your product is sensitive to high temperatures?

Comment: Yes Qwerty exactly!

Comment: @seleneflemming I don't know your academic level, but if you are genuinely interested in it you may do a research in this aspect(thanks I too have added it on my first project list ), I am aware of microwave assisted solvent extraction, vaccum assisted solvent extraction is also there but perhaps nobody has clubbed it with soxhlet. I guess design of apparatus will pose challenge in maintaining vaccum, but there's possibility to do it. It's utility will also be major factor.